# Django: SECRET_KEY improperly configured error in settings.py when importing a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-authentication

I wanted to authenticate users by email so I wrote a `EmailBackend` class in `backends.py`.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['backends.EmailBackend']
```

I made this change in settings.py as said.

[image: Project structure]

My backends.py file is a brother of settings.py (both sit in the same main directory). However, when I run this, I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backends'
```

When I try to import this file in settings.py using

```
from .backends import EmailBackend
```

I get an error that secret key is incorrectly configure, when I have,'t even touched the key:

```
  File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\myDjangoSite\myDjangoSite\settings.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .backends import EmailBackend
  File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\myDjangoSite\myDjangoSite\backends.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

The same happens even if I move backends.py into my app's folder.

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS array (blog is my own app):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'bootstrap3'


]
```

Comment: Have you since found a solution to this? Encountering the same thing. SECRET_KEY exists and the project works fine until I try to import a module with a few simple functions into the Django's settings file.